# Dataflow outputting "Error unmounting disk" logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I have a streaming Dataflow pipeline, and I'm seeing errors like the following:

```
error unmounting disk mydisk-6245203-05194249-aiaiai-harness-disk-0, error=generic::unknown: Failed to execute shell command=umount -v /windmill/ahab0-guoliang0oon-6245203-05194249-aiaiai-harness-disk-0, exit code=8192, errno=0, output: , command output:
```

Is this a problem for my pipeline? Am I dropping data or slowing down my pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

When a Dataflow job autoscales or load-balances, the Persistent Disks that the streaming backend uses for its intermediate data storage are unmounted and remounted on different VMs.

The unmount errors by themselves do not indicate a problem with the pipeline.  If the actual workers and desired workers converge within a few minutes, that indicates that autoscaling is likely working fine.

---

Dataflow also has [Streaming Engine](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#streaming-engine) as a streaming backend. Streaming engine does not use Persistent Disks for state storage - instead it uses a separate service. Unmounting errors should not appear on streaming engine jobs. (But also, note that unmounting errors are not a problem as long as the pipeline is working well otherwise).